# Object as faults - CoreData Relationship

Tags: swift, core-data

I got 2 entities:

1. Todo
2. Dates

They are connected with inverse relationship so one Todo object can have multiple Dates, so Todo has properties:

```
@NSManaged var dates: NSSet?
@NSManaged var name: String?
```

and each Dates object can have one Todo, so it has property:

```
@NSManaged var todo: Todo?
@NSManaged var wasDone: NSNumber? //It is a boolean
@NSManaged var date: NSDate?
```

When I create a Todo I insert new object in entity name.

```
//Saving into local device context
        guard let ourcontext = self.context else {print("no context");return}
        guard let newTodo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Todo", inManagedObjectContext: ourcontext) as? Todo else {return}
        let myTodoName = self.addTodoView.searchTextField.text
        newTodo.name = myTodoName
```

Then I calculate the dates and I want to insert them into NSSet of Todo (I made a function in Todo:

```
func addObject(value: Dates) {
        let dates = self.mutableSetValueForKey("dates")
        dates.addObject(value)
    }
```

so after calculating the dates and creating "datesArray" of them I want to add them to mentioned above NSSet:

```
for _ in self.datesArray {
            guard let newDate = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MedicineDates", inManagedObjectContext: ourContext) as? MedicineDates else {return}

            newTodo.addObject(newDate)
```

Here is the first question - did I create the relationship between the objects correctly?

Then I want to create (in cellForRowAtIndexPath, as this is displayed in a tableView) an Array from the NSSet of Todo:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TodoTableViewCell
        guard let object = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Todo else {return cell}
```

NSSet to Array:

```
let fetchedData = object.dates?.allObjects as! [Dates]
let datesArray = [NSDate]()
for object in fetchedData {
    datesArray.append(object.date!)
}
```

And here is the boom. When I try to unwrape the object.date it tells me that  "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" but I know that fetchedData with objects of "Date" type in it exists .

What is the thing that I did wrong or I did not do?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that while the `Dates` objects exist, their `date` attribute of type `NSDate` does not.

Make sure that you created the `Dates` object correctly by setting its `date` attribute and *saving* the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a typed Set instead so you can save some lines of code:

```
@NSManaged var dates: Set<Dates>?
```

But the error indicates that the object of type `Dates` contains a `nil` attribute `date`. This is because `date` is defined optional and has not been initialized.

You could define as non optional the attribute `date` in the data model and set a default value. And then define in your subclass:

```
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
```